# MySQL syntax error while creating a new table

Tags: php, mysql

I have no issues with the query in the below code. But the second code is throwing the error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Working code :

```php
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error());

$result ="  CREATE TABLE google_csv(
    ÿþName varchar(80),
    Given_Name varchar(80),
    Additional_Name varchar(80),
    Family_Name varchar(80),
    Yomi_Name varchar(80),
    Given_Name_Yomi varchar(80),
    Additional_Name_Yomi varchar(80),
    Family_Name_Yomi varchar(80),
    Name_Prefix varchar(80),
    Name_Suffix varchar(80),
    Initials varchar(80),
    Nickname varchar(80),
    Short_Name varchar(80),
    Maiden_Name varchar(80),
    Birthday varchar(80),
    Gender varchar(80),
    Location varchar(80),
    Billing_Information varchar(80),
    Directory_Server varchar(80),
    Mileage varchar(80),
    Occupation varchar(80),
    Hobby varchar(80),
    Sensitivity varchar(80),
    Priority varchar(80),
    Subject varchar(80),
    Notes varchar(80),
    Group_Membership varchar(80),
    E_mail_1___Type int(11),
    E_mail_1___Value int(11),
    E_mail_2___Type int(11),
    E_mail_2___Value int(11),
    Phone_1___Type int(11),
    Phone_1___Value int(11),
    Phone_2___Type int(11),
    Phone_2___Value int(11),
    Phone_3___Type int(11),
    Phone_3___Value int(11),
    Address_1___Type int(11),
    Address_1___Formatted int(11),
    Address_1___Street int(11),
    Address_1___City int(11),
    Address_1___PO_Box int(11),
    Address_1___Region int(11),
    Address_1___Postal_Code int(11),
    Address_1___Country int(11),
    Address_1___Extended_Address int(11),
    Website_1___Type int(11),
    Website_1___Value int(11)
)";

echo $result;

mysql_query($result);
echo mysql_error();
?>
```

Error producing code;

```
<?php

// GENERATE TABLE FROM FIRST LINE OF CSV FILE

$inputFile = 'google.csv';
$tableName = 'google_csv';

$fh = fopen($inputFile, 'r');
$contents = fread($fh, 5120); // 5KB
fclose($fh);

$fileLines = explode("\n", $contents);

$fieldList = explode(',', $fileLines[0]);

$lastField=count($fieldList)-1;

echo "Total Fields :".count($fieldList)."<br>";

echo "Last Field :".$lastField."<br>";

$result ="CREATE TABLE $tableName(";

for($i = 0; $i < count($fieldList); $i++)
{
    if(preg_match('/[1-9]/', $fieldList[$i]))
    {

    if ($i==$lastField)
    {$result .=str_replace(array(" ",'-'),"_",$fieldList[$i]). ' int(11)';}
    else
    {$result .=str_replace(array(" ",'-'),"_",$fieldList[$i]). ' int(11),';}

    }
    else
    {

    if($i==$lastField)

    {$result .=str_replace(array(" ",'-'),"_",$fieldList[$i]). ' varchar(80)';}
    else
    {$result .=str_replace(array(" ",'-'),"_",$fieldList[$i]). ' varchar(80),';}

    }
}

$result .=")";

if ($result) {echo $result."<br>".$i."<br>";} else {Echo "Some Problem!";}

mysql_connect("localhost", "","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query($result);

echo mysql_error();

?>
```

I am using the `$result` output from here in the first code and it works perfectly fine! Where am I going wrong in the second code?

The $result echo  gives

> CREATE TABLE google_csv(ÿþName varchar(80),Given_Name varchar(80),Additional_Name varchar(80),Family_Name varchar(80),Yomi_Name varchar(80),Given_Name_Yomi varchar(80),Additional_Name_Yomi varchar(80),Family_Name_Yomi varchar(80),Name_Prefix varchar(80),Name_Suffix varchar(80),Initials varchar(80),Nickname varchar(80),Short_Name varchar(80),Maiden_Name varchar(80),Birthday varchar(80),Gender varchar(80),Location varchar(80),Billing_Information varchar(80),Directory_Server varchar(80),Mileage varchar(80),Occupation varchar(80),Hobby varchar(80),Sensitivity varchar(80),Priority varchar(80),Subject varchar(80),Notes varchar(80),Group_Membership varchar(80),E_mail_1_**Type int(11),E_mail_1**_Value int(11),E_mail_2_**Type int(11),E_mail_2**_Value int(11),Phone_1_**Type int(11),Phone_1**_Value int(11),Phone_2_**Type int(11),Phone_2**_Value int(11),Phone_3_**Type int(11),Phone_3**_Value int(11),Address_1_**Type int(11),Address_1**_Formatted int(11),Address_1_**Street int(11),Address_1**_City int(11),Address_1_**PO_Box int(11),Address_1**_Region int(11),Address_1_**Postal_Code int(11),Address_1**_Country int(11),Address_1_**Extended_Address int(11),Website_1**_Type int(11),Website_1___Value int(11))

Looks like all is fine here ! But then......

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [**red box**](http://php.net/mysql-connect)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, try [this article](http://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing). If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Would you be able to `echo $result;` just prior to sending to the query? If the first bit of code is working, it is more likely that someone has gone bonkers during the PHP code and the create table query isn't what you think it is.

Comment: the $result echo is CREATE TABLE google_csv(ÿþName varchar(80),Given_Name varchar(80),Additional_Name varchar(80),Family_Name......

Comment: @user1407430 Would you be able to pop the whole result into the question by editing it? The syntax error could be anywhere in it mate.

Comment: sure Fluffeh...in a minute...

Comment: @user1407430 I will have to agree with rkosegi on this one - I think the first column name is borking your code or mysql somehow. Would you be open to renaming it and trying again?

Comment: @Fluffeh, this is a column name generated from the CSV file by the code...this is supposed to be a standard sript to convert CSVs.  How do we know that any of those may generate the same thing ?

Comment: @Fluffeh, I did str_replace for the characters to _ but it still gives the error..

Answer (score 0):

What is this :

> ÿþ

```
$result ="CREATE TABLE google_csv(ÿþName ....")

           -----------------------^
```

ÿþ are special charecters (0xFE, 0xFF). I don't think that OP want them in colum name, if so, it should be enclosed by

```
`ÿþName`
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1

Comment: I noticed that when I was editing the question for formatting, but the OP says it is working code?

Comment: $result echoes CREATE TABLE google_csv(ÿþName varchar(80),Given_Name varchar(80),Additional_Name varchar(80),Family_Name...

Comment: @user1407430 From a good column name practise, make easy to type column names. As I said before, it was the first thing I saw when looking at your question. I would suggest trying to rename the field and you will likely find that the rest of your code falls into place.

Comment: @rkosegi this is a column name generated from the CSV file by the code...wouldnt renaming become a trying task ?

Comment: ÿþ - is UTF-8 BOM. it is added as first two bytes in UTF8 files in some cases.

Comment: @Yossarian, any ideas about to how to get round that or removing it ?

Comment: @user1407430 I found this [reference](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=377068) which suggests that your column name is invalid unless you surround it with a backtick as suggested in this answer. In your code, instead add appending `columnName` add in \`columnName\`

Comment: Thanks a ton for all the answers, guys. @Fluffeh, just one quick clarification, did you mean that I need to change $FileList to `$fileList` ? Forgive my ignorance, I have learnt this bit of programming all  by myself...so bound to look dumb..

Comment: @user1407430 Sorry, am very tired, I meant enclosing your column names with a \` (normally next to the character 1 on a keyboard) character. I edited my comment a few minutes ago when I saw the error, but you must have read the original.

Comment: No issues Fluffeh,I too have edited the comment..should I add ` to the variable $fileList in the For Loop ?

Comment: No. When reading from the CSV file, you should use UTF-8 aware methods, they will get rid of the BOM. I'm not however sure how to do this in PHP, that's why I did not responded as an answer.

Comment: @Fluffeh I have added the backtick to column names and still not working...Thanks for all the efforts, guys...

Comment: @Yossarian, thanks for the input...I guess I need to google again to find out how to do that...thanks again anyways..